# Word's alternative to Latex's command for replacing text

Tags: microsoft-word

In latex, if I want to put some repetitive expression in the main text, an easy approach is to define a command for it, e.g.

```
definition: \newcommand{\thesis}{thesis}
usage: I work on my phd \thesis.   ->   output: I work on my phd thesis.
```

and if I want to change the expression as many times as I want, it is only needed to update the command:

```
update: \newcommand{\thesis}{dissertation}
usage: I work on my phd \thesis.   ->   output: I work on my phd dissertation.
```

Is there something like this in MS Word?

Answer (score 0):

The Word "equivalent" is "AutoCorrect".

You add entries, which may look like "\thesis => thesis", in menu
File, Proofing section, press the button "AutoCorrect Options...".

References :

- [Add or remove AutoCorrect entries in Word](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-or-remove-autocorrect-entries-in-word-e7433b94-f3de-4532-9dc8-b29063a96e1f)
- [Turn AutoCorrect on or off in Word](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/turn-autocorrect-on-or-off-in-word-9f5a0684-05f6-4510-b419-8f0034caefe4)

Comment: AutoCorrect only replaces the text, does not track it for future update. I want something like fields that can be updated during printing.

Comment: [How to Insert Fields in Microsoft Word (Built-in or Custom)](https://www.avantixlearning.ca/microsoft-word/how-to-insert-fields-in-word-built-in-or-custom/).